# Find the limit of $\lim_{x\to0^+}[\ln(1+x)]^x$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}[\ln(1+x)]^x$$

I tried the following, but simply plugging in $0$ above gives $0^0=1$, so wondering what is flawed in my approach below:

Let $y=\ln^x(1+x)=x\ln(1+x)$

$\exp(y=x\ln(1+x))$

$e^y = e^{x\ln(1+x)}$

$e^y = e^{x\cdot(x+O(x^2))}=e^{x^2+O(x^3)}$

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^+}e^y=\lim_{x\to0^+}e^{x^2+O(x^3)} = e^0=1$

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^+}\ln e^y= \ln1$

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^+}y=0$

Comment: Simply inserting and getting $0^0$ does _not_ mean, in any way, that the limit should be $1$. It still might be, but that's like saying $\frac00=1$.

Comment: @Arthur Isn't $lim_{x\to0^+}x^x=1$? So wouldn't that mean I could say $0^0=1$ in that sense?

Comment: And $\lim_{x\to0}\frac xx=1$. You still don't go around saying that $\frac00=1$.

Comment: $log(1000)=3, (log(100))^2=9$. Whereas,  $log(1000^2)=2\cdot log(1000)=6$. Counterexample to your first line, asserting that $ln^x(1+x)=xln(1+x)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit of the logarithm is
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}x\ln\ln(1+x)
$$
With $1+x=e^t$, it becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}(e^t-1)\ln t=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{e^t-1}{t}(t\ln t)
$$
The first factor has limit $1$, the second factor has limit $0$. So the limit is $0$ and, finally,
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\bigl(\ln(1+x)\bigr)^x=e^0=1
$$

Note that
$$
\bigl(\ln(1+x)\bigr)^x\ne\ln\bigl((1+x)^x\bigr)
$$
so this is a major flaw in your argument.

Comment: Ok so I solved the wrong problem, seems like I accidentally solved $\lim_{x\to0^+}\ln((1+x)^x)$ instead of what was asked for.

Comment: @user17753 Seems so. `;-)`

Comment: Is there another way to go about solving this one without having noticed that clever substitution? Or is that a common approach to solving these kinds of problems?

Comment: @user17753 Taking the logarithm is mosto fo the times a winning strategy. Instead of that substitution, you could go with $x=1/t$ and then apply l'Hôpital.